# How can i scroll to next div after clicking on radio button or check box using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to scroll a `div` to down after clicking on a checkbox or a radio button. Below is HTML of my popup where there is a list of radio buttons and checkboxes which are added in a `ul` in HTML:

```html
<div id="toppings-properties-modal" class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 10000; transform: none !important; display: block;" aria-modal="true" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content mb-3">
      <div class="modal-body pb-3" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;max-height:70vh;overflow-y:auto">
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-12 py-3" style="background: white;border-radius: 25px;">
            <div id="menu-item-img" class="product-img-modal mx-auto" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://foods.qmanja.com/MenuImages/Menu5099-SingleCheese.jpg.png&quot;);"></div>
            <h5 id="menu-item-name" class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-3 fs_18 fw-bold">Single Cheese Pizza</h5>
            <p id="menu-item-desc" class="txt_dark f_merriweather lh-base fs_12">Whether you're a cheese connoisseur or simply crave the comforting taste of a traditional cheese pizza, our Single-Sliced Cheese Pizza is the perfect choice. I</p>
            <h5 class="txt_dark mb-0 mt-2 fs_18 fw-semibold">₹ <span id="menu-item-price">100</span>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12" id="menu-item-properties" style="display: block;">
            <div class="mb-2 mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_18 fw-bold">Select any one option</h5>
              <p class="fs_12 m-0 required-prop">Required</p>
            </div>
            <ul id="menu-item-properties-list" class="topping-list">
              <li>Giant <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>₹&nbsp;400</span>
                  <label class="container-radio">
                    <input name="menu-property" data-price="400" type="radio" *checked="checked" *="" onchange="propertyChanged(3408)">
                    <span class="checkmark-radio"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Large <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>₹&nbsp;300</span>
                  <label class="container-radio">
                    <input name="menu-property" data-price="300" type="radio" onchange="propertyChanged(3617)">
                    <span class="checkmark-radio"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Medium <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>₹&nbsp;200</span>
                  <label class="container-radio">
                    <input name="menu-property" data-price="200" type="radio" onchange="propertyChanged(2821)">
                    <span class="checkmark-radio"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Regular <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>₹&nbsp;100</span>
                  <label class="container-radio">
                    <input name="menu-property" data-price="100" type="radio" onchange="propertyChanged(2822)">
                    <span class="checkmark-radio"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12" id="menu-item-toppings" style="display: block;">
            <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-2 fs_18 fw-bold">Crust Pizza [Giant]</h5>
            <p class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_12"> You can select upto 1 option</p>
            <ul class="topping-list">
              <li>Cheesy Crust <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;181</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-646" data-toppingid="2189" data-maxqty="1" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="181" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Achari Crust <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;38</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-646" data-toppingid="2190" data-maxqty="1" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="38" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-2 fs_18 fw-bold">Extra Cheese [Giant]</h5>
            <p class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_12"> You can select upto 1 option</p>
            <ul class="topping-list">
              <li>Extra Cheese <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;134</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-647" data-toppingid="2191" data-maxqty="1" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="134" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-2 fs_18 fw-bold">Extra Topping [Giant]</h5>
            <p class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_12"> You can select upto 20 option</p>
            <ul class="topping-list">
              <li>Pineapple <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2237" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Red Paprika <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2238" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Jalapeno <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2239" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Fresh Tomato <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2240" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Golden Corn <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2241" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Mushroom <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2242" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Paneer <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2243" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Capsicum <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2244" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Onion <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2245" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>Black Olives <div class="d-flex">
                  <span>+&nbsp;₹&nbsp;91</span>
                  <label class="container">
                    <input name="menu-topping-654" data-toppingid="2246" data-maxqty="20" data-ispropertytopping="true" data-price="91" type="checkbox" onchange="selectToppings(this)">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h5 class="txt_dark m-0 fs_18 fw-semibold">Total Price : ₹ <span id="menu-item-total-price">100</span>
        </h5>
        <a class="add-to-cart-modal" onclick="addToCart()" style="pointer-events: none; color: rgb(149, 146, 146);">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a script which I have added:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function scrollModalBodyToBottom() {
        var modalBody = $('.modal-body');
        if (modalBody.length) {
            // Find the next ul element
            var nextUl = $(this).closest('.col-12').next().find('ul');

            if (nextUl.length) {
                var isCheckbox = $(this).is(':checkbox');
                var maxQty = isCheckbox ? parseInt($(this).data('maxqty')) : 1;

                if (isCheckbox) {
                    // Check if the limit for checkboxes is reached
                    var selectedCheckboxes = $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox:checked').length;
                    if (selectedCheckboxes >= maxQty) {
                        nextUl = nextUl.filter(':not(:has(:checkbox:checked))');
                    }
                }

                if (nextUl.length) {
                    var maxHeight = modalBody.prop('scrollHeight') - modalBody.height();
                    modalBody.animate({ scrollTop: maxHeight }, 'slow');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $('#toppings-properties-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        // Use event delegation to handle dynamically added elements
        $('.modal-body').on('change', 'input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"]', scrollModalBodyToBottom);
    });
});
```

I want when a user clicks on ready button, it should scroll down to the next list added. In the `ul` there are two cases:

1. When a user clicks on a radio button, then it should scroll to next `ul` list.
2. When a user clicks on checkbox, it should not move to the next one until the checkbox limit has been reached. For example, if I have a 5 items in a `ul` with checkboxes and I have allowed to select 2 items or 1 item from that list, when the checkbox limit is reach, only then it should scroll to next `ul`.

Essentially, if I have radio buttons that means there is only a single item and if there is are checkboxes then user should be able to select multiple options with a limit of selection.

The given JavaScript is working but I'm stuck in implementing the scroll to the next `div` and I also need a condition as per radio button and checkboxes.

Comment: Without fully analysing the question, might be [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Execute on selection limit

We can use the `data-maxqty` attribute value that exists on the checkboxes to determine the limit in `scrollModalBodyToBottom()`:

```js
// If a radio, the limit is always 1, otherwise, parse from
// `data-maxqty` attribute.
const limit =
  this.type === 'radio' ? 1 : parseInt(this.dataset.maxqty ?? 1, 10);
```

Then, we can check how many checkboxes/radios are checked for the current group:

```js
// Gives an array of elements that have the same `name` attribute that are
// checked.
const checked = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(this.name)).filter(
  (option) => option.checked,
);
```

Then, have an `if` that checks `checked.length` in relation to `limit`:

```js
if (limit <= checked.length) {
  // …
}
```

## Scroll to next list

It seems it would be best user experience to scroll to the next *heading* once the limit of options have been selected. It seems like the structure is that a  `<h3>` for the next list follows the `<ul>` of the current list. In this case, we can use `.nextElementSibling`:

```js
// `this` is the `<input>` element checked/unchecked. We get the parent
// `<ul>` and get the next element sibling with `.nextElementSibling`.
// This should be the heading for the next list of options.
const next = this.closest("ul").nextElementSibling;
if (next) {
  // Scroll this heading into view.
  next.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

```js
window.selectToppings = () => {};

$(document).ready(function () {
  function scrollModalBodyToBottom() {
    const limit =
      this.type === "radio" ? 1 : parseInt(this.dataset.maxqty ?? 1, 10);

    const checked = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(this.name)).filter(
      (option) => option.checked,
    );
    if (limit <= checked.length) {
      const next = this.closest("ul").nextElementSibling;
      if (next) {
        next.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    }
  }

  $("#toppings-properties-modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", scrollModalBodyToBottom);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", scrollModalBodyToBottom);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-b2QcS5SsA8tZodcDtGRELiGv5SaKSk1vDHDaQRda0htPYWZ6046lr3kJ5bAAQdpV2mmA/4v0wQF9MyU6/pDIAg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-WW8/jxkELe2CAiE4LvQfwm1rajOS8PHasCCx+knHG0gBHt8EXxS6T6tJRTGuDQVnluuAvMxWF4j8SNFDKceLFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#toppings-properties-modal">
  Show modal
</button>

<div
  id="toppings-properties-modal"
  class="modal fade"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-modal="true"
  role="dialog"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content mb-3">
      <div
        class="modal-body pb-3"
        style="background-color: #f5f5f5; max-height: 70vh; overflow-y: auto"
      >
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div
            class="col-12 py-3"
            style="background: white; border-radius: 25px"
          >
            <div
              id="menu-item-img"
              class="product-img-modal mx-auto"
              style="background-image: url(&quot;/img/Offer_Dish-1.png&quot;)"
            ></div>
            <h5
              id="menu-item-name"
              class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-3 fs_18 fw-bold"
            >
              Special Pizza (Medium)
            </h5>
            <p
              id="menu-item-desc"
              class="txt_dark f_merriweather lh-base fs_12"
            >
              Cheese: A combination of mozzarella, cheddar, or other cheeses is
              typically used to create a gooey and melty layer that covers the
              pizza.
            </p>
            <h5 class="txt_dark mb-0 mt-2 fs_18 fw-semibold">
              ₹ <span id="menu-item-price">500</span>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12" id="menu-item-properties" style="display: none">
            <div
              class="mb-2 mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
            >
              <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_18 fw-bold">
                Select any one option
              </h5>
              <p class="fs_12 m-0 required-prop">Required</p>
            </div>
            <ul id="menu-item-properties-list" class="topping-list"></ul>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12" id="menu-item-toppings" style="display: block">
            <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-2 fs_18 fw-bold">
              Special Pizza Crust
            </h5>
            <p class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_12">
              You can select upto 1 option
            </p>
            <ul class="topping-list">
              <li>
                Thin Crust
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-681"
                      data-toppingid="2354"
                      data-maxqty="1"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Cheesy Crust
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-681"
                      data-toppingid="2355"
                      data-maxqty="1"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Achari Crust
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-681"
                      data-toppingid="2356"
                      data-maxqty="1"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-2 fs_18 fw-bold">
              Special Pizza Topping
            </h5>
            <p class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_12">
              You can select upto 5 option
            </p>
            <ul class="topping-list">
              <li>
                Pineapple
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2357"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Red Paprika
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2358"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Jalapeno
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2359"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Fresh Tomato
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2360"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Golden Corn
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2361"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Mushroom
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2362"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Paneer
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2363"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Capsicum
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2364"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Onion
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2365"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Black Olives
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="menu-topping-682"
                      data-toppingid="2366"
                      data-maxqty="5"
                      data-ispropertytopping="false"
                      data-price="0"
                      type="checkbox"
                      onchange="selectToppings(this)" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-2 fs_18 fw-bold">
              Radios
            </h5>
            <p class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_12">
              You can select upto 1 option
            </p>
            <ul class="topping-list">
              <li>
                Foo
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="radios"
                      value="foo"
                      type="radio" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Bar
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="radios"
                      value="bar"
                      type="radio" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Baz
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="radios"
                      value="baz"
                      type="radio" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <h5 class="txt_dark f_merriweather mb-2 mt-2 fs_18 fw-bold">
              More checkboxes
            </h5>
            <p class="txt_dark f_merriweather fs_12">
              You can select upto 2 options
            </p>
            <ul class="topping-list">
              <li>
                Foo
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="checkboxes"
                      value="foo"
                      type="checkbox" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Bar
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="checkboxes"
                      value="bar"
                      type="checkbox" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                Baz
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <label class="container"
                    ><input
                      name="checkboxes"
                      value="baz"
                      type="checkbox" /><span
                      class="checkmark"
                    ></span
                  ></label>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
        <h5 class="txt_dark m-0 fs_18 fw-semibold">
          Total Price : ₹ <span id="menu-item-total-price">500</span>
        </h5>
        <a class="add-to-cart-modal" onclick="addToCart()" style=""
          >Add to Cart</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Wongjn thank you for this help its working with check box but i have also radio button when Im click on it this.closest("ul").nextElementSibling getting null at that time can you  let me know how to fix it with that too

Comment: i have updated a html please check

Comment: Consider consolidating your HTML so it is more consistent. The other sections aren't wrapped in a `<div>` – they are together in the same parent – but the radios *are* wrapped in their own separate `<div>`. Either consolidate your HTML so it is more consistent or adjust the JavaScript for this special case.